# Reporting Services Error "Could not load file or assembly 'Spring.Web' or one of its dependencies"

Tags: reporting-services

After installing and configuring Reporting Services on a virtual site with a ASP.NET MVC running on the root folder, I get this "Error" :

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Spring.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\blc\web.config line 171)

Source Error: 


Line 169:           <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 170:           <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 171:           <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
Line 172:           <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate21"/>
Line 173:       </httpModules>


Source File: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\blc\web.config    Line: 171
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Spring.Web.dll is in your bin folder?

Comment: I am having the same problem